# Multiple update using GORM in Golang

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am trying to make APIs using GIN and GORM. Now i have stucked in one of the APIs. This API will create multiple entries in the DB.
I have the json body like this. The size of array will vary.

```
{
 "key" : [1,2]
}
```

With this, I have some other parameter that i am getting from the url-

```
key1 := c.Param("value1")
key2 := c.Param("value2")
```

Now i want to create multiple entries [1,2] on DB with data of key1 and key2 like-

| Key1 | Key2 | key |
| --- | --- | --- |
| value1 | value2 | 1 |
| value1 | value2 | 2 |

I am stuck at the point where i dont know how to read this json and save the data in my schema (struct) to create multiple entries like-

```
var users = []User{{key1: "value1", "key2": "value2, "key" :1}, {key1: "value1", "key2": "value2, "key" :2}}
db.Create(&users)
```

Please guide me to a possible solution as i am new to Go.
Let me know for more clarifications. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Structs needed

1. Request json

```
type BodyJson struct {
    Key []int `json:key`
}
```

2. User table struct for gorm

```
type User struct {
    Key  int    `gorm:"column:key"`
    Key1 string `gorm:"column:key1"`
    Key2 string `gorm:"column:key2"`
}
```

Unmarshal body json to BodyJson struct var

```
var bodyJson BodyJson
err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(body_json_string), &bodyJson)
```

loop over `bodyJson.Key` array and populate an [] of `User` with this key, key1 and key2.

Then save the users with

```
db.Create(&users)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey thanks buddy! It worked.
Also got to know about https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/ to convert a json to Go struct.